# Значение переменной GET получается пустым

Tags: ajax, php

Здравствуйте. Делаю фильтр продуктов на joomla 2.5. Когда отправляю текст с помощью ajax в обработчик, то значение покачивает GET показывает NULL. Вот код:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".sort").change(function(){
    var sel = $(".sort option:selected").text();
    $("#fon").css({'display':'block'});
    $("#load").fadeIn(1000, function(){
        $.ajax({
url:'/rosservis/components/com_joomlakassa/views/category/tmpl/default.php',
            data:'sort_sel='+sel,
            type:'GET',
            seccess:function(html){
                alert(html);}
        });
    });
});
```

А вот PHP в файле default.php

```
if (isset($_GET['sort_sel'])){
    echo 'Hello';}
else var_dump($_GET['sort_sel']);
```

Когда изменяю ссылку, чтобы в консоле увидит ошибку, выдается ошибка:
GET http://localhost/components/com_joomlakassa/views/category/tmpl/default.php?sort_sel=Ariston 404 (Not Found) - И тут видно что sort_sel=Ariston, А в NUUL. Не подскажете где ошибка?

Comment: 404 значит не отвечает по url сервер.

А вот данные я бы передал так:
 
    data: {sort_sel: sel} (Хотя и со строкой должно работать)

Comment: Да это я специально написал ссылку неправильно, чтобы на консоле увидить sort_sel пустая или нет, и видно что не пустая.

Comment: Может быть, что Joomla пропускает все через роутер, и делает редирект на без ГЕТовую ссылку. в default.php на сайте, а не неверном адресе, сделайте вывод текущего адреса и посмотрите. может получается что-то типа /components/joomkassa/sort_sel/Ariston/

Comment: А в этом случае как отправить данные?

Comment: можно постом отправить, можно гетом и посмотреть как они получаются. в J1.5, там был класс JRequest, и через него бралось. посмотрите API по фреймворку. Но вначале нужно проверить, может я не прав )))